# Salted password with AES encryption

Tags: encryption

I am encrypting a text file using AES 256 encryption. Does it add much to the security of the file’s contents to also add a salted password to the file? (I don’t believe it would add much) Can a salted password be added as part of the encryption process to make the encryption itself more secure? ( I don’t believe so - my understanding is that salting only makes the password more difficult to determine, not the encryption )

Comment: What does "add a salted password to the file" mean? But, if you are using a password as opposed to a random key, the encryption key should be derived from the password, a standard method is to use PBKDF2 with an iteration count such that it consumes ~100ms of CPU time. That is a starting point, there are many ways to jeopardized security.

Comment: @zaph hello and thx for getting back to me. I am wondering how a salted password relates to an AES encrypted file? Would it be part of the encryption process itself? And, if so, is it necessary or beneficial or minimally helpful in protecting the file that is encrypted? AES 256 encryption is so strong I’m wondering how password would help. I guess any added protection is worth it. Or in this case only minimally.

Comment: the password is used to generate the key that encrypts the data, what would you generate the key with if not a password?

Comment: AES is a primitive, a secure encryption scheme needs more including key derivation, random IV, authentication and secure construction. If the encryption key is weak it makes no difference how strong the encryption algorithm is. The attack vector is a weak encryption key or possibly a CBC Oracle if padding errors are returned to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Passwords are not keys. Keys consist of a specific number of randomized bits. So to encrypt a file using a password (password based encryption or PBE) you first need to create a key from a password.

Password hashes or Password Based Key Derivation Functions are the schemes that consume a password, a salt, a work factor (or iteration count) and possibly other parameters (parallelism, memory usage) and then produce a key. Known PBKDFs are PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2.

The salt is mainly used for two reasons: making sure that duplicate passwords do not derive the same key and avoiding rainbow table attacks. Producing the same key is not a big issue during encryption; you can use an IV to create a different ciphertext. Rainbow table attacks are more problematic: you can create a table with keys derived from passwords and try and decrypt: this would allow an attacker to test keys without minding the work factor.

As you can also derive an IV with a PBKDF you might as well use a salt. This would make PBE indeed more secure for the reasons stated above. So yes, you should use an up to date PBKDF such as Argon2, a strong password, a large work factor and - indeed - a salt during encryption.

Comment: There are many more pitfalls, better use PGP or something similar.